# Lucene.net, Error indexing a document with Filed.Store.COMPRESS

Tags: c#-4.0, lucene.net

I'm developing a index, and need to store values compressed, because its needed to show that info to the user.
I've the current error: "Can not load ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll", when I do the `writer.AddDocument(doc);`

The DLLs are from NuGet, and I've the SharpZipLib because is a dependecy of Lucene.net.

Snippet:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);  
Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(directoryInfo);  
Analyzer analyzer = new SnowballAnalyzer("Portuguese");  
bool isNew = !IndexReader.IndexExists(directory);  
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, isNew, Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);  
//Create document  
Document doc = new Document();  
NumericField numericField = new NumericField("id", Field.Store.YES, false);  
numericField.SetIntValue(id);  
doc.Add(numericField);  
Field field = new Field("title", title, Field.Store.COMPRESS, Field.Index.ANALYZED);  
field.SetBoost(7);  
doc.Add(field);  
field = new Field("description", tescription, Field.Store.COMPRESS, Field.Index.ANALYZED);  
doc.Add(field);  
writer.AddDocument(doc);  
writer.Optimize();  
//Close the writer  
writer.Commit();  
writer.Close();  
}  
catch (Exception ex)  
{ throw ex; }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That means lucene cannot find the SharpZipLib DLL in your build path, make sure it is copied to the output of your project

Note that compressed fields are deprecated in recent versions of Lucene, I would not recommend to use them. You should use the CompressionTools class instead, or roll out your own compression methods.

Comment: But I've referenced the SharpZipLib in project.
Thanks for the tip, I'm looking forward for more information.

Comment: Make sure the DLL is named exactly ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll and that the Copy Local property of the reference in your VisualStudio project is set to true

Comment: All these requirements are set, and it's awkward its appended... :(

Comment: Old trick, but make some random call to something directly in ICSZL in your code and redeploy, I've seen some cases where 3rd party referenced DLLs would just not come along for the ride without said hokey tricks.